# Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment but it is in my encrypted file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a 6.0.2 rails app and everything seems to work fine in development (I can create the database and run the app on a localhost). However, I'm stuck trying to make it work in production. I have a `master.key` file containing my key and a `credentials.yml.enc` file containing: `secret_key_base: 123...` (with my real key of course).

With this, I'm trying to run `RAILS_ENV=production rails db:setup` but it always fails with the following error:

```
rails aborted!
ArgumentError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this string with `rails credentials:edit`
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:580:in `validate_secret_key_base'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:423:in `secret_key_base'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:24:in `key_exists?'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/secret_key_finder.rb:16:in `find'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/devise-4.7.1/lib/devise/rails.rb:37:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
/Users/victor/Documents/SaaS projects/myblog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/zeitwerk-2.3.0/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:339:in `require_environment!'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:23:in `block in perform'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/rake/rake_command.rb:20:in `perform'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:48:in `invoke'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
/Users/victor/Documents/SaaS projects/myblog/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
/Users/victor/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/victor/Documents/SaaS projects/myblog/bin/spring:15:in `require'
/Users/victor/Documents/SaaS projects/myblog/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:setup => db:schema:load_if_ruby => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I'm really confused here, because it says that there's no `secret_key_base` but it is defined in my `credentials.yml.enc` (it's the only thing in there!)

I looked at a bunch of other stackoverflow questions and saw that this problem is usually due to the old way Rails has to handle encrypted files (but I'm in 6.0.2 so this shouldn't be an issue...). The only other answer I found suggested to delete the `master.key` and `credentials.yml.enc` and create new ones with `rails credentials:edit`, which I did, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the environment along like should help with this problem.

```
rails credentials:edit --environment production
```